# No value from hiera on puppet manifests when installed foreman

Tags: puppet, hiera, theforeman

If try to get data from module use calling_class the data don't come to puppet manifests, if put the variable to common or osfamily yaml file value will be available from manifets.
My environment:
Puppet Master 3.7.4 + Foreman 1.7 + Hiera 1.3.4
Hiera configs:

```
    ---
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - "%{::environment}/node/%{::fqdn}" #node settings
  - "%{::environment}/profile/%{calling_class}" # profile settings
  - "%{::environment}/%{::environment}" # environment settings
  - "%{::environment}/%{::osfamily}" # osfamily settings
  - common # common settings
:yaml:
  :datadir: '/etc/puppet/hiera'
```

*/etc/puppet/hiera/production/profile/common.yaml*

```
profile::common::directory_hierarchy:
  - "C:\\SiteName"
  - "C:\\SiteName\\Config"
profile::common::system: "common"
```

And on profile module manifest  */etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/profile/manifests/common.pp*

```
class profile::common (
      $directory_hierarchy      =undef,
      $system                   =undef
  )
{
  notify { "Dir is- $directory_hierarchy my fqdn is $fqdn, system = $system": }
}
```

Puppet config */etc/puppet/puppet.config*

```
[main]
    logdir = /var/log/puppet
    rundir = /var/run/puppet
    ssldir = $vardir/ssl
    privatekeydir = $ssldir/private_keys { group = service }
    hostprivkey = $privatekeydir/$certname.pem { mode = 640 }
    autosign       = $confdir/autosign.conf { mode = 664 }
    show_diff     = false
    hiera_config = $confdir/hiera.yaml
[agent]
    classfile = $vardir/classes.txt
    localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
    default_schedules = false
    report            = true
    pluginsync        = true
    masterport        = 8140
    environment       = production
    certname          = puppet024.novalocal
    server            = puppet024.novalocal
    listen            = false
    splay             = false
    splaylimit        = 1800
    runinterval       = 1800
    noop              = false
    configtimeout     = 120
    usecacheonfailure = true
[master]
    autosign       = $confdir/autosign.conf { mode = 664 }
    reports        = foreman
    external_nodes = /etc/puppet/node.rb
    node_terminus  = exec
    ca             = true
    ssldir         = /var/lib/puppet/ssl
    certname       = puppet024.novalocal
    strict_variables = false
    environmentpath  = /etc/puppet/environments
    basemodulepath   = /etc/puppet/environments/common:/etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules
    parser = future
```

And the more interesting thing that if deploy the same code without foreman it will be working. 
Maybe I've missed some configuration or plugins?

Comment: I believe I have the same issue, same versions of puppet / foreman / hiera. If i do `hiera -c /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml classes role=test ` I get the correct returns for my hierarchy, but my nodes checkin and nothing happens. I turned on debug logging on puppet via passenger, and it seems to be loading the correct hiera.yaml, but nothing actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need have a environment (`production` in your sample) folder structures as below:

```
/etc/puppet/hiera/environments/production/node/%{::fqdn}.yaml
/etc/puppet/hiera/environments/production/profile/%{calling_class}.yaml
/etc/puppet/hiera/environments/production/production/*.yaml
/etc/puppet/hiera/environments/production/%{::osfamily}.yaml
/etc/puppet/hiera/environments/common.yaml
```

So the environment path you pasted is wrong also.

```
/etc/puppet/hiera/production/profile/common.yaml
```

---

#### Side notes

By first view, shouldn't mix hieradata with modulepath, so if can, move the modules out of basemodulepath

```
basemodulepath   = /etc/puppet/environments/common
```

With the puppet.conf you pasted, the real profile module path is at one of three folders:

```
/etc/puppet/environments/common/modules/profile
/etc/puppet/modules/profile
/usr/share/puppet/modules/profile
```

Comment: I think you read it wrong...  datadir + hierarchy would be `/etc/puppet/hiera/production/node`

Comment: If you read again, you will know my answer is for fixing the issue and provide recommendation.